# Optional Conditions in Where Statement MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ReviewLogs.Models
{
    public class SearchModel
    {

        [Display(Name = "Type: ")]
        public int? type { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Server: ")]
        public string curServer { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Status: ")]
        public string status { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "User Name: ")]
        public string searchedUser { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Month Ending: ")]
        public int? monthEnd { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Year Ending: "),
        RegularExpression("^([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Year must be entered and a valid 4 digit number")]
        public int? yearEnd { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Min Log Date: ")]
        public string minLogDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Max Log Date: ")]
        public string maxLogDate { get; set; }



        [Display(Name = "Ticket Number: ")]
        public string ticket { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Comment: ")]
        public string comment { get; set; }

        public SearchModel()
        {
            searchedUser = " ";
        }
    }
}
```

A Controller:

```
        public ActionResult LogSearch()
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                loadDropDown();
                return View();

            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogSearch(SearchModel submission)
        {
            loadDropDown();




            return RedirectToAction("NameSearchList", "Search", new { userName = submission.searchedUser ,type = submission.type.Value});


        }

public ActionResult NameSearchList(int? type, string userName = "")
        {


                var cnn = new reviewlogsEntities();

                return View(cnn.logrecords.Where(m => m.username == userName && m.typeid == type));




        }
```

And A View:

```
    @model ReviewLogs.Models.SearchModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Review";
}

@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/datetimepicker_css.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/CurDropDownChecker.js"></script>

}


}


<h2>Add Review</h2>
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Submission Failed, Please Try Again")
<p id="success">@ViewBag.SuccessMessage</p>
<div class="formBody">

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="inputOthers">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.type)
            @Html.DropDownList("type", ViewBag.type as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "", new { onchange = "setDisplay();" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.type)
        </div>
    <div class="inputOthers">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.searchedUser)
        @Html.DropDownList("searchedUser", ViewBag.users as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, " ")

    </div>
        <div class="inputOthers">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.curServer)
            @Html.DropDownList("curServer", ViewBag.server as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, " ")

        </div>

        <div class="inputOthers">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.status)
            @Html.DropDownList("status", ViewBag.status as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, " ")

        </div>

        <div class="inputOthers">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ticket)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ticket)

        </div>
        <div class="inputOthers">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.comment)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.comment, new { style = "width:320px; height: 160px;" })

        </div>

        <div class="inputOthers">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.minLogDate)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.minLogDate, new { @readonly = "readonly" })

            <a href="javascript: NewCssCal('logDate','mmddyyyy','arrow',true,12)">
                <img src="~/Images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Pick a date">
            </a>

        </div>

     <div class="inputOthers">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.maxLogDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.maxLogDate, new { @readonly = "readonly" })

        <a href="javascript: NewCssCal('logDate','mmddyyyy','arrow',true,12)">
            <img src="~/Images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Pick a date">
        </a>

     </div>

        <div class="inputOthers">
            <span id="monthEnd">

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.monthEnd)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.monthEnd, ViewBag.months as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, " ")

            </span>

            <span id="yearEnd">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.yearEnd)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.yearEnd, new { @Value = DateTime.Now.Year })

            </span>


        </div>
        <input class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-left:126px;margin-bottom: 20px;" onclick="return confirm('If you would like to submit press OK');" />

    }
</div>
```

So if you look at this there are many optional fields that the user can enter. If they enter data in that field then it is added onto the search results. Right now if they enter a type and searchedUser it will bring up the page with the corresponding data. However the problem I'm trying to resolve is what if they don't enter a type. I don't want that search coming up. Right now it does this:

```
http://localhost:51730/Search/NameSearchList?userName=Admin&type=1
```

But lets say they don't search for a name but only a type. How can I make sure that "userName=Admin" won't show up. I want to restrict each one if they are not entered or NULL and only the ones entered.

Could you show please show a solution for how I would go about having optional requirements?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend to check out [MCVE] guidance and clean up code in your post so only minimal related code is left. Currently code makes post very long and bad formatting does not improve visitor's impression which may cause people to ignore the question and possibly downvote it too.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for adding conditional filters ignoring nulls in your NameSearchList action

Option 1: check for nulls inside the where statement

```
var q = cnn.logrecords.Where(m => (m.username == userName || string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) && (m.typeid == type || !type.HasValue))
return View(q);
```

Option 2: add where statements only for those not null parameters

```
var q = cnn.logrecords;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
{
    q = q.Where(m => m.username == userName);
}
if(type.HasValue)
{
    q = q.Where(m => m.typeid == type);
}
return View(q);
```